# mdadm using double disk space

Tags: mdadm, raid1, proxmox

My mdadm raid1 2 disks array seems to work good.
It is a 2 500GB array, shared over samba as proxmox bkup disk serving 2 nodes.
By the way, even if the size of the sum of the files is actually about 20GB, proxmox reveals 44GB occupied.

Any idea about what's happening and how possibly solve this?

Comment: What does `df -h` show?

Comment: `:/mnt/bkup/proxmox$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md127      458G   18G  417G   5% /mnt/bkup`

Comment: 458 -417 = 41GB occupied, while 18GB used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually 5% of a file system is reserved for root to recover the system in situations where users have filled disk space. This makes sense for essential partitions, such as `/`, but perhaps less so in other cases.

However, the reserved space is what you're seeing: 18GB is in use, and 5% of 458GB is 22.9GB. 22.9GB + 18GB is 40.9GB - which explains the 417GB available.

Note that *you* make the leap from size - used = occupied, which is not the case, due to the 5% reserved for root. Those 5% can be used by root, but not by normal users.

If you want, you can change the reserved amount. How to do that depends on the type of the filesystem.

Comment: thank u.. didn't know about the reserved 5%